# How to implement octomape on Ros-Melodic⁷

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have 3d point collection defined at (x,y,z), I have published these points via sensor_msgs/pointcloud2 , now I am trying to map these messages with octomap, please I need the command list to install octomap on melodic and run it around my pointcloud2 message, at github I can not find the version for melodic
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362026/how-to-implement-octomape-on-ros-melodic%E2%81%B7/) by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Next time try to do a search before ask, please!

here you have the package http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server.

So

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-octomap ros-melodic-octomap-server ros-melodic-octomap-mapping ros-melodic-octomap-ros ros-melodic-octomap-msgs
```

then just run:

```
roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch
```

btw your pointcloud has to be named cloud_in, or do a remap to change it's name to /narrow_stereo/points_filtered2. so, in you launch file you should add:

```
<remap from="cloud_name" to="/narrow_stereo/points_filtered2" />
```

And you have to define the global frame as a parameter (check the wiki) by default is /map but maybe is not your case.
You have to publish also a transform between this frame and the sensor data frame if you don't know how, here you have tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials).

I think that's all! Hope it works

---

Originally posted by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) with karma: 187 on 2020-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/76126/hesham/) on 2021-12-06**:
Thanks for answering the question and also for asking it! Its page http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server isn't detailed enough like that.